# Modal window gets truncated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, bootstrap-modal

I am very new to angular js. But whenever i set the laptop resolution - 1366 x 768’ my popup gets truncated.

Whenever the content increase for the popup the popup gets truncated. This is how i open my popup

```
 $scope.openPreviousOrdersPopup= function(){
    $scope.siteInputError= null;
    previousOrdersPopup = $modal({
      template: 'partials/editQuoteRequest/previousOrdersPopup.html',
      show: true,
      persist: true,
      backdrop: 'static',
      scope: $scope
    });
  };
```

The code for the popup is :

```
<!-- Confirmation popup for closing the quote request without save -->
<div id="transitionPopupId" popup-dispatcher="transitionPopupId" style="overflow :auto; max-height: 40%">
  <div class="modal-header"  >
    <h3 ng-if="customerTeamList && customerTeamList.length == 1" style="float: left;font-size: 13px;" translate>popup.newComment</h3>
    <h3 ng-if="customerTeamList && customerTeamList.length > 1" style="float: left;font-size: 13px;" translate>popup.chooseAndComment</h3>
    <h3 ng-if="!customerTeamList && quoteRequest.status == 'draft'" style="float: left;font-size: 13px;" translate>popup.newComment</h3>
    <h3 ng-if="quoteRequest.status !== 'Draft'" style="float: left;font-size: 13px;" translate>popup.commentTitle</h3>
    <div class="buttonClose" ng-click="inProgress.submit = false;closeDetailQr();dismiss();removeParent('transitionPopupId');"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: auto ;padding-bottom: 0px;overflow-y: hidden" class="modal-body">

    <div style="max-height: 240px;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden">
      <div ng-if="customerTeamList && customerTeamList.length > 1 && quoteRequest.status != constants.yourInputRequired"
           style="background: #E4E4E4; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 515px"
           ng-repeat="customerTeam in customerTeamList">

        <input type="radio" ng-model="quoteRequest.customerTeamId" ng-value="customerTeam.localCustomerTeamId" ng-change="changeCustomerTeam(customerTeam)" style="float: left; margin-top: 13px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px">

        <div style="padding: 10px">
          <div style="float: left; width: 45%">
            <p style="font-weight: bold">{{customerTeam.localCustomerTeamName}}</p>
            <p class="paragraph">{{customerTeam.localCustomerTeamDescription}}</p>
          </div>

          <div style="float: right; width: 45%">
            <p class="paragraph">{{customerTeam.localQuoteOwner.localFirstName}} {{customerTeam.localQuoteOwner.localLastName}}</p>
            <p class="paragraph">{{customerTeam.localQuoteOwner.localPhone}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class={{required}} translate>popup.messageToQO</p>

    <div ng-form="commentForm">
    <p ng-show="showErrorSubmitComment" style="color: red">The comment is required.</p>
    <textarea id="submitComment"
              name = "submitComment"
              my-maxlength="200" rows="5"
              style="width:500px;margin-bottom: 0px;height: 80px"
              ng-model="rejectionComment.value">
    </textarea>

    </div>
      <div ng-show="showAddEmail">
      <!--add additional email ids at quote request submission step> <!-->
      <div ng-form="ccEmailForm" id="emailRecipients" >
    <div>
        <p translate>profile.notifAdditionnalEmailRecipients</p>
        <span class="tooltipInfo ng-scope" tooltip="notification for creation of this Quote request will also be sent to the email addresses provided" tooltip-placement="right" style="float: right; margin-right: 338px; margin-top: -28px;"></span>
    </div>

    <div ng-init="initForm(ccEmailForm)">

            <div style="float: left">
                <input type="text" name="listAdditionalEmailAddresses" ng-model="addEmailvalue" style="float: left" ng-pattern="/^{{constants.email_validation}}$/">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <p style="margin-left: 5px;text-align: left; " ng-show="ccEmailForm.listAdditionalEmailAddresses.$error.pattern" class="formError" translate>form.wrongFormatEmail</p>
            </div>
            <button class="bouton_action" style="margin-left: 30px" ng-click="addAdditionalEmails()"  translate>button.addEmail</button>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <select style="height: 100px !important;" id="myselection" multiple size="5" ng-model="listEmailAddressToDelete" ng-multiple=true style="float: left" ng-options="ccEmail as ccEmail for ccEmail in listAdditionalEmailAddresses">
            </select>
            <button class="bouton_action" style="margin-left: 30px" ng-click="delAdditionalEmails()" translate>button.deleteEmail</button>
    </div>

      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="modal-footer" >
    <button class="bouton_action" ng-click="inProgress.submit = false;manageOrderRejection(false);closeDetailQr();dismiss();removeParent('transitionPopupId');" translate>button.cancel</button>
    <button class="bouton_action" ng-disabled="!quoteRequest.customerTeamId" ng-click="manageOrderRejection(true);submit()" translate>button.ok</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

code to calculate top position

```
app.directive('popupDispatcher', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, linkElement, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {scope.$watch
            (
                function () {
                    return  linkElement.height();
                },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue > 0) {
                        if(typeof scope.initPosition == 'function'){
                            // call the initPosition function if size of the popup has change
                            $timeout(function() {scope.initPosition(String(attrs.popupDispatcher));}, 200);
                        }
                        else{
                            // call the initPosition function if size of the popup has change for isolated scope of a directive
                            $timeout(function() {scope.$root.initPosition(String(attrs.popupDispatcher));}, 200);
                        }

                    }
                }
            )},300); // 300 corresponds to animation delay to display popup
        }
    };
}]);



// set the popup position depending on scroll position
$rootScope.initPosition = function(id){
    if (iframeId != "" && iframeId != null) {
        var thePopup = $('#' + id).parent();
        $rootScope.myPopupId = id;
        var popupPosition = $(window.parent.document).scrollTop();
        if (popupPosition < 100) {
            popupPosition = 100;
        }
        var deltaPosition = (popupPosition + thePopup.height()) - ($(window).height() -20);

        // in case of truncated popup resize the iframe
        if(deltaPosition > 0 && id != "loadingPopupId"){
            contentResize(popupPosition + thePopup.height() + 20);
        }
        // set the horizontal scrollBar
        var scrollLeftPos = ($(window).width() - thePopup.width()) / 2;
        $(window).scrollLeft(scrollLeftPos);
        thePopup.css('position','absolute');
        if(id=='transitionPopupId' && deltaPosition > 0){
            thePopup.css('top',deltaPosition - 20);
        }else{
            thePopup.css('top',popupPosition);
        }

    }

};




/**
 * Function called by the heightWatcher directive to call the resize function of the parent (MSS integration)
 */
var contentResize = function (height) {

    if(typeof height == "undefined") {
        height = $("#parentDivForOQT").height();
    }

    if( height< 500) {
        height = 500;
    }

    $("body").height(height+20);
    if(parent.iframeResize) {
        parent.iframeResize(iframeId); //set by back-office to the value retrieved from URL
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it get truncated horizontally or vertically? 
The div with class modal-body has overflow-y: hidden which will truncate the content if it is too high. 
The div with max-height also has overflow-x: hidden which would truncate the content if it is too wide.

Comment: my modal window gets truncated vertically

Comment: So remove the overflow-y: hidden directive. Does that help?

Comment: No that does not help.. the real problem is with resolution.. when i display the popup in desktop resolution its okay but when i display it in laptop resolution it get truncated.. we have code to calculate top position.. but i am not able to figure out the problem.